# Laravel: Change result of input query to friendly url

Tags: laravel, forms, seo

How can I change this URL generated from submitting the form-

`http://localhost:8000/estates?zone=London&type=villa`

to this URL:

`http://localhost:8000/estates/London/villa`

Need to make the URL more friendly for search engines.

I get the **zone** and **villa** from input fields in a form in

`localhost:8000/estates`

When I submit the form I get a URL like this-

`localhost:8000/estates?zone=London&type=villa`

Instead of above I would like to have this URL when I submit the form-

`localhost:8000/estates/London/villa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form, it should catch the post data in controller action like this-

```
class MyController
{
    public function create()
    {
        // Your form
    }

    public function store()
    {
        // This is where you receive the zone and villa in the request
    }
}
```

As you can see you have received the input field in request in your store method, now you can do something like this-

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Your code here
    redirect()->to($request->zone.'/'.$request->villa);
}
```

Please make sure you have the **routes** created for zone and villa otherwise redirecting to a non-existing **route/url** will not work.

Create a route like this for your request-

```
Route::get('estates/{zone}/{villa}', 'MyController@anotherMethod');
```

You will have another action method in your controller to receive this **zone** and **villa** inputs like this-

```
public function anotherMethod($zone, $villa)
{
    // Access your $zone and $villa here
}
```

Comment: dud have another q, its work good in search engine ?
this q is for im not good in this case!

Comment: Parameter URLs are not good for SEO. So yes, the URL structure like this estates/zone/villa is better. You can read more about this matter here- https://moz.com/blog/15-seo-best-practices-for-structuring-urls

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure your routes so zone and village become route parameters.

So, for example, the route for http://localhost:8000/estates/London/villa would be `Route::post('/estates/{zone}/{villa}', 'SomeController@action')` and in the controller you can inject the *zone* and *village* as parameters. So you can use something like this :

```
class SomeController {
         public function action(Request $request, string $zone, string $villa){

         }
}
```

It is described further in the Route parameters section of Routing in Laravel docs.

Comment: dud i forget to write this: i  get the zone and villa from input in a from in http://localhost:8000/estates and wanna when they submit form this url
http://localhost:8000/estates?zone=London&type=villa change to this url
http://localhost:8000/estates/London/villa
i will change the q, sry my bad